# How to load balance containers?

Tags: nginx, docker, load-balancing, haproxy, coreos

### How to load balance docker containers running a simple web application?

I have 3 web containers running in a single host. How do I load balance my web containers?

Comment: This sounds like 2 separate questions. You probably should edit the post to have only 1 in it and ask the other question separately

Comment: I have made it 2 questions.

Comment: you have qualifier for the `docker run` command to allocate more or less CPU and memory to your containers, see https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run for the CPU you have `-c, --cpu-shares=0         CPU shares (relative weight)` and for the memory `-m, --memory=""            Memory limit (format: <number><optional unit>, where unit = b, k, m or g)`

Answer (score 11):

Put a load balancer, such as haproxy or nginx can even do the job.

[Decent Haproxy Documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-http-load-balancing-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

[Nginx Howto](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

Either way, put the load balancer on the host or on a different server that can access the exposed ports on the containers. Nginx will probably be simpler for your needs.

To setup basic nginx load balancing:

> ```
> http {
> upstream myapp1 {
>     server CONTAINER_APP0_IP:PORT;
>     server CONTAINER_APP1_IP:PORT;
>     server CONTAINER_APP2_IP:PORT;
> }
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://myapp1;
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes this solution would work in  a one docker host situation. But how will it work when my docker container is running in a container platform like coreos ? I want to achieve autoscaling and auto reconfiguration of the proxy depending on the load.

Comment: Just put nginx on a server in front of the host. Aside from using service discovery, this is the simple way.

Comment: thanks, we can use nginx/haproxy to forward the requests to the containers. But I want to know how auto-reconfiguration of proxy server happens depending on the state of containers in etcd ? Do we need to use some other tool/(or write it) to solve it or do we already have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question, that is not what you asked originally and that is a very different question.